# How to prevent Y axis from rescaling every time I move the slider in manipulate

Tags: plotting, functions, rescale

I am trying to plot the intensity distribution of Double Slit DIffraction, I have used the manipulate function to manipulate Cos[p] which is for interference in the following code, but when I move the slider, instead of the peak going up, the Y-axis rescales such that the plot remains exactly same which defeats the purpose of using the function to visualize the change

```
Manipulate[Plot[(1*Sin[x]/x*Cos[p])^2, {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Orange, Filling -> Bottom, PlotRange -> All], {p, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}]
```

Comment: use `PlotRange -> {{-3 Pi, 3 Pi}, {0, 1}}`?

Comment: Note that `Sin[x]/x == Sinc[x]` and `Sinc[x]` has the advantage of being defined for `x == 0`

Comment: `Manipulate[
 Plot[(Sinc[x]*Cos[p])^2, {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Orange, 
  Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> 1], {p, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}]`